# How can I view the data area that an app collects?

Tags: insufficient-memory, cache, app-data

How can I view the data area of each app. My storage gets filled up, and I have to clear the app cache within each app thru settings-->app-->storage often. I'm curious that some apps I rarely use seem to have huge data sizes, and I'd like to see what info they are collecting. Is there any kind of software that would let me see the data area of each app? I'm using android 9. I'd prefer a way that doesn't need to root my device if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible without root. Even with root there is no guarantee a user would be able to make sense of the collected data. It is all about context and the context is known only to app developers. // You could try taking backup of some apps (if it is permitted by those apps) using adb and investigate the backup. The backup file contains the app data.

Comment: @Firelord how do I backup with adb and view it that way? Also is there a way to do a full backup of my android, app and data areas, to my computers storage, so I will have an accessible backup in case I need to restore? Is it done thru adb also? Is root needed? I'm hesitant to root because I don't have a backup I'd need to restore from if the rooting goes bad... Thanks in advance

Comment: The question that you are asking me has been answered a lot many times here on this site and on sites on the net. Try a search query such as "how to take app backup using adb?" or "How to take full device backup using adb?". Your questions would be answered by any of those queries.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thank you for the quick reply!